# Is it safe to delete all the content from .gradle and .idea?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am facing an issue that I can see a suggestion someone made on a blog that supposedly helped them solve the same issue. The suggestion was to delete all content on .Gradle and .idea folder, followed by gradle re-sync and rebuild all.

I am fairly a beginner and I've never done anything like that, so I am scared of any destructive actions I don't know the results of. Is there anything to be afraid of by this action, or would these files just be regenerated again?

If all good, how is it done properly? Via the explorer? Or via Android Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.gradle/` and `.idea/` are safe to delete, though I would have the IDE not be open on that project while you do it. If that is your only project, close Android Studio, then delete those directories using your OS file explorer or the command line. Then, reopen Android Studio, and it will recreate and re-populate those directories.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the other answers be sure to save the content already in the files. For instance, in your app/build.gradle file be sure to save content like your SDK version and dependencies. When your app is rebuilt and synced you may have to find code relying on a certain SDK Version or dependency.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can delete the .gradle and .idea folder from the file explorer when the android studio is not open, android studio will automatically generate these 2 folders when you will open the project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).